# How can I integration Spotify in ionic 2 framework application?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, spotify

I am creating the app in ionic 2 but I don't know how can **I integrate Spotify in ionic**.

ionic doesn't provide any plugin So what can I do?

Thankful,
Karmdip Joshi

Comment: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/

Comment: take a look at this demo app from Mike Hartington: [Spotify seach app written with Ionic 2](https://github.com/mhartington/star-track-ionic).